# Getting the params data point value for the tooltip callback function in echarts?

Tags: javascript, typescript, echarts

I'm trying to get the value for [this Apache EChart](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-animation-delay) within the callback of the tooltip formatter.

If I hardcode the value then this formatting function works:

```
formatter: (params:any) => `$ ${Math.round(parseInt('100.000', 10))}`,
```

The tooltip displays `$ 100`.

However if I replace `100.000` with `params.value`, the value is `NaN`.  How do we access the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up doing the trick:

```
formatter: (params:any) => `$ ${Math.round(parseInt(params[0].value, 10))}`,
```

This is the demo in case anyone wants to play with the code.

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-animation-delay